# Java: Multiple Classes and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently in a Java course this semester (completely new to programming and struggling a bit with multiple classes and arrays). The current program I am working on is a Sudoku type game using a 2D array. The instructors have given us a class for Constant numbers in this array (the initial values in the Sudoku puzzle). Here is the code for it.

```
public class Constants {
 public static int game[][] = new int[][] {
{ 1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 8 },
{ -1, -1, 4, -1, 8, -1, 7, 1, -1 },
{ -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 5, 3, -1 },
{ 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1, -1 },
{ -1, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, 6, 5, -1 },
{ 7, 5, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
{ -1, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 9, -1 },
{ 3, -1, 1, 8, 5, -1, -1, -1, 6 },
{ 5, 6, -1, 9, -1, 7, -1, -1, -1 } 
};
```

The values of -1 refer to blank spaces in the puzzle.

Basically all I need to know is.. how would I access this array or these values in my other Class and main method? Once again I apologize for being completely new to java, thank you in advance.

Comment: You instructor doesn't know what constants or conventions are. `public static final int GAME[][]`

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee I'd say the OP doesn't know what constants are.  I believe that the program is going to want to modify the values in `game`

Comment: You should still be able to modify the values in `game` even if it is declared as `static final`.

Comment: Yeah, I mean constants as in... just a number they'll give us. This constants file will be replaced with a new one with the same variable names and all, just different numbers in different positions.

Answer (score 5):

You would access the actual `game` variable with

```
Constants.game
```

and you can access individual members of the array with

```
Constants.game[i][j]
```

where `i` is the row and `j` is the column of the element you are trying to access.